# Why starting Artifactory fails

Tags: docker, ubuntu, artifactory

I want to install **artifactory** on an ubuntu docker image manually without using the **artifactory** image from docker hub.

what I have done so far is :

- Get an ubuntu image with JDK 11 installed.
- I used apt-get I have installed the artifactory.

but when starting the artifactory service with `service start artifactory` I get the following logs with errors:

```
root@f01a31f43dc0:/# service artifactory start
2021-12-15T23:57:37.545Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [artifactory:81                ] [main] - Starting Artifactory tomcat as user artifactory...
2021-12-15T23:57:37.590Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [installerCommon.sh:1519       ] [main] - Checking open files and processes limits
2021-12-15T23:57:37.637Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [installerCommon.sh:1522       ] [main] - Current max open files is 1048576
2021-12-15T23:57:37.694Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [installerCommon.sh:1533       ] [main] - Current max open processes is unlimited
.shared.security value is of wrong data type. Correct type should be !!map
.shared.node value is of wrong data type. Correct type should be !!map
.shared.database value is of wrong data type. Correct type should be !!map
yaml validation failed
2021-12-15T23:57:37.798Z [shell] [WARN ] [] [installerCommon.sh:721        ] [main] - System.yaml validation failed

Database connection check failed Could not determine database type
2021-12-15T23:57:38.172Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [installerCommon.sh:3381       ] [main] - Setting JF_SHARED_NODE_ID to f01a31f43dc0
2021-12-15T23:57:38.424Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [installerCommon.sh:3381       ] [main] - Setting JF_SHARED_NODE_IP to 172.17.0.2
2021-12-15T23:57:38.652Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [installerCommon.sh:3381       ] [main] - Setting JF_SHARED_NODE_NAME to f01a31f43dc0
2021-12-15T23:57:39.348Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [artifactoryCommon.sh:186      ] [main] - Using Tomcat template to generate : /opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/conf/server.xml
2021-12-15T23:57:39.711Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [artifactoryCommon.sh:1008     ] [main] - Resolved ${artifactory.port||8081} to default value : 8081
2021-12-15T23:57:39.959Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [artifactoryCommon.sh:1008     ] [main] - Resolved ${artifactory.tomcat.connector.sendReasonPhrase||false} to default value : false
2021-12-15T23:57:40.244Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [artifactoryCommon.sh:1008     ] [main] - Resolved ${artifactory.tomcat.connector.maxThreads||200} to default value : 200
2021-12-15T23:57:40.705Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [artifactoryCommon.sh:1008     ] [main] - Resolved ${artifactory.tomcat.maintenanceConnector.port||8091} to default value : 8091
2021-12-15T23:57:40.997Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [artifactoryCommon.sh:1008     ] [main] - Resolved ${artifactory.tomcat.maintenanceConnector.maxThreads||5} to default value : 5
2021-12-15T23:57:41.278Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [artifactoryCommon.sh:1008     ] [main] - Resolved ${artifactory.tomcat.maintenanceConnector.acceptCount||5} to default value : 5
2021-12-15T23:57:41.751Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [artifactoryCommon.sh:1008     ] [main] - Resolved ${access.http.port||8040} to default value : 8040
2021-12-15T23:57:42.041Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [artifactoryCommon.sh:1008     ] [main] - Resolved ${access.tomcat.connector.sendReasonPhrase||false} to default value : false
2021-12-15T23:57:42.341Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [artifactoryCommon.sh:1008     ] [main] - Resolved ${access.tomcat.connector.maxThreads||50} to default value : 50
2021-12-15T23:57:42.906Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:527       ] [main] - Resolved JF_PRODUCT_HOME (/opt/jfrog/artifactory) from environment variable
2021-12-15T23:57:43.320Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [artifactoryCommon.sh:1008     ] [main] - Resolved ${shared.tomcat.workDir||/opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/work/artifactory/tomcat} to default value : /opt/jfrog/artifact
ory/var/work/artifactory/tomcat

========================
JF Environment variables
========================

JF_SHARED_NODE_ID                   : f01a31f43dc0
JF_SHARED_NODE_IP                   : 172.17.0.2
JF_ARTIFACTORY_PID                  : /var/run/artifactory.pid
JF_SYSTEM_YAML                      : /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/system.yaml
JF_PRODUCT_HOME                     : /opt/jfrog/artifactory
JF_ROUTER_TOPOLOGY_LOCAL_REQUIREDSERVICETYPES : jfrt,jfac,jfmd,jffe,jfob
JF_SHARED_NODE_NAME                 : f01a31f43dc0
2021-12-15T23:57:45.827Z [shell] [ERROR] [] [installerCommon.sh:3267       ] [main] - ##############################################################################
2021-12-15T23:57:45.890Z [shell] [ERROR] [] [installerCommon.sh:3268       ] [main] - Ownership mismatch. You can try executing following instruction and do a restart
2021-12-15T23:57:45.959Z [shell] [ERROR] [] [installerCommon.sh:3269       ] [main] - Command : chown -R artifactory:artifactory /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/log
2021-12-15T23:57:46.029Z [shell] [ERROR] [] [installerCommon.sh:3270       ] [main] - ##############################################################################
```

I'm not sure what I'm messing in this installation process.

Comment: There is insufficient information. Please, provide docker-compose and Dockerfile for artifactory image. But, for first look something wrong inside of config files of the artifactory or environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

The error is clear that there is permission issue on  **/opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/log** folder and you should be running the **chown -R artifactory:artifactory /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/log** command to solve it